# With PHP it's possible to get the IP of a intermediate server?

Tags: php, ip, server

The problem is the next: 
In my company we have our main server in a certain city, and we have another branch offices on another cities, each one with it own server that are connected to the main server. So, when a PC, tablet, or smartphone connects to our webpage (in the main server) in whatever of those branch offices I need to display certain data according to that server. Is there a way to get the IP of the server in each branch office?

Comment: `server that are connected to the main server` what does it mean?

Comment: @Lashane Probably the entire internet :)

Comment: You already asked the same question earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29973987/3933332

Comment: @Rizier123 It's deleted.

Comment: @Barmar It's still unfair against all other people which asks a question to repost the same question, to then get more attention. The question would be why OP delete the old one when he still needs an answer?!

Comment: I feel like this is something that's done by parsing http logs, and less stressing on PHP

Comment: @Ye. I think he wants the target server to return different results depending on the original office. Log parsing is something you do in batch after the fact.

Comment: @Rizier123 Either way, the question was deleted, so this one is not a duplicate. You can't exactly flag it as a duplicate of a deleted question.

Comment: @Mike *Either way* no, it's just unfair against all other users which are asking a question and waiting for an answer. If they see such a question and see that he reposted the same question, do you think they won't also repost their question to get more/new attention?! And that I think is not how SO works!

Comment: @Rizier123 I definitely agree that it's abusing the system, but what exactly could be done about it? I can't think of anything feasible. Preventing people from deleting their question isn't really an option. Preventing people from posting a question with the same text isn't really an option because they would just have to change a few words and it wouldn't be exactly the same. Maybe prevent new users from posting a new question after they delete one? I'm sure there are legitimate reasons to do that, so people would get upset. Can you think of a way to prevent it?

Comment: @Mike *Can you think of a way to prevent it?* Of course: 1. Show the user that this is not how SO works and that this is unfair to other users, so they understand it why they shouldn't do it. 2. Show them the possibilities which they have to edit their questions and clarify the problem more! 3. Give them useful links to the help center how to ask a good question, so that they can write a good question and don't have to abuse the system

Comment: @Rizier123 How would you even detect it though?

Comment: @Rizier123 I mean how would you detect that someone is deleting a question and reposting it without causing adverse side effects? First, there are probably legitimate reasons to do so, like "Aha! I figured it out (*deletes question*) ... no wait, on second thought, that didn't work". And there also [isn't a way to view your deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/179506). I can't see there being a workable way to actually detect that someone is abusing things until it is too late. Correct me if I'm wrong. Maybe it's a better discussion for Meta anyway. Post it up!

Comment: @Mike 1. *I can't see there being a workable way ... until it is too late* Yeah sadly there is no way until it's too late, but it's not too late to show OP why he shouldn't do that.  2. *like "Aha!* Could happen, but then OP can undelete the question. I mean there is a reason for this button (Or mention it in the new question). 3. As in your link you can see your delete questions/answers within 60 days. Also if you copy a part of the question and use google you will also find the delete questions. (But I don't think here is the right place do discuss this, so I will stop here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proxy servers in the branch offices should add a `Via` header, containing the name of the proxy. The PHP script can then parse `$_SERVER['HTTP_VIA']` to get this information. The details of this header can be found in [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.45).

Comment: Ok, I will try this ;)
In the other hand, now is a fact that is a terrible idea practice english making questions on StackOverflow.